# Библиотека gettext в lua

Tags: lua, gettext

Необходима библиотека `gettext` для `lua` (CGI-сайт). Какие существуют решения?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.debian.user.russian/KE_0A4-iEfg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение на `ffi`: https://github.com/bungle/lua-resty-gettext. Данная реализация просто пробрасывает все библиотечные функции gettext напрямую.

Answer (score 3):

библиотека которая несет в себе нужный функционал используется как в cocos2d фреймворке так и сама по себе, по ссылке пример использования [ссылка на github](https://github.com/zrong/lua#Gettext). Так же нужный функционал есть в [API World of Warcraft](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/API_GetText), но насколько знаю использование его за пределами игры невозможно.

Comment: присуждаю награду как наиболее близкому к требованиям конкурса ответу. хотя, конечно, ожидалась пошаговая инструкция и пример использования.

Comment: Работает ли данная библиотека с формами мн. числа?